# Is arithmetic allowed in a Java array subscript?

Tags: java, arrays

Is it legal Java syntax to access data in an array index by calculating the subscript in the calling line? Something like so:

```
int[] foo = new int[10];
int bar = foo[3-1];    //attempts to set bar = foo[2]
```

Comment: why don't you try it ?

Comment: It is easy to check it than posting a question. I'm sure

Comment: I'm not near a compiler. Is it really that ludicrous to ask a question for the benefit of future programmers with the same question?

Comment: Future programmers will try it themselves.

Comment: Except the ones who aren't near a compiler and still want to know. Now, back inside your horcrux Voldemort

Comment: @Cody ideone.com is available if you're on SO. Or, of course, [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3).

Comment: Thanks! @AndyTurner

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. You assign a array to an int...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Any calculation that ends up in an `int` can be used in an array access.  (It can throw if it's outside the array range or negative, of course, but it'll compile.)  [The JLS specifies this behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3).

Answer (score 4):

As long as the expression in the subscript evaluates to an `int`, then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can put in between those [] whatever you what that result to be an integer at the time you compile... anything else is not going to compile

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] foo = { 1, 0, 1, 3 };
    int bar = foo[3 - 1];
    bar = foo[1.0];// invalid since is a double
    bar = foo[1L];// invalid since is a long
    bar = foo[args.length];// valid
    bar = foo[3 - 1];// valid
    bar = foo[Double.valueOf(0).intValue()];// valid
    bar = foo[x];// valid if x is an int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is legal, unless your calculation is not wrong and the result is an `int`, because this can guide you to an error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: xxx` if the calculation is wrong (great or less then the size of your array), so be careful.